# How do I find what bitrate a CPU/GPU can decode?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, gpu, h.264, htpc

I'm exporting videos to play locally on a dedicated player with a [CPU like this.](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/96507/intel-celeron-processor-3865u-2m-cache-1-80-ghz.html)
The integrated GPU supports up to 4096x2304@60Hz, I assume that's talking about uncompressed video, right?

I also see it has [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) which I believe means it can decode h.264/5.

What I can't seem to determine is the maximum bitrate it should be able to handle. I see on the Quick Sync Wikipedia page that KabyLake is marked *Yes(L5.1)*. Does this mean all those CPUs should be able to playback bitrates of  [up to 240mbps](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Advanced_Video_Coding#/Levels)? Even still it's not apparent what h.264 profile I should be using.

Sorry if the answer should be obvious, I've just failed to find somewhere that just spells it out and provide clarity.

Comment: I have no idea, but I don’t think this is a simple question in the least. It really depends on the video codec. For example, many MP4 videos are encoded in x264 format which is a GPU friendly codec. But then again, nowadays many videos are being encoded with x265 (h265/HEVC) as the codec which is a heavy CPU dependent codec. And to make matters more confusing _some_ GPUs have onboard x265 decoding capabilities, but you need to check it to make sure it supports x265.

Comment: One way only : test it for your case.

Comment: Yea it all seems kind of all over the place, not as simple as knowing the hardware speeds and bandwidths and being able to determine it I guess.

damn, I wonder if there's at least a way to benchmark it instead of making a ton of test videos. I'll have to dig deeper into that

Comment: Intel Celeron 3865U includes Intel HD Graphics 610 GPU. According to [this page](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/hd_graphics_610), Hardware Accelerated Video Capabilities supports AVC (H.264) high profile and Level 5.1. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding), you can find the property values of the level. The maximum bitrate is 240,000. The maximum specified resolution is 4,096×2,304@26.7Hz. (it doesn't mean it is going to work, there may other bottlenecks).

Answer (score 0):

That's 4096x2304@60Hz on a DisplayPort. It just means that the iGPU is able to send 60 frames per second to the monitor and that is all. 24 frames per second if using HDMI. I can only assume that 60 FPS playback should be trivial for new-ish hardware.

This has absolutely nothing to do with the decoding power of the hardware. If you're transcoding video then you need to look for those specific benchmarks.

FYI, a dual-core laptop CPU is going to be abysmally slow at transcoding 4K video.